# What's the meaning of this error message "insertId: Error: INVALID_ACCESS_ERR: DOM Exception 15"?

Tags: jquery, cordova, mobile-safari

I'm developing an app using jquery mobile, phonegap and openDatabase. When the app is executed, I can see in the console of Safari browser the **SQLResultSet** with this message:

```
insertId: Error: INVALID_ACCESS_ERR: DOM Exception 15.
```

However, my app is working ok. But I don't understand why that message is shown.

Please, help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that no row was inserted by a transaction, by that it's more  an information than an error.

If an INSERT-statement wasn't successfull or an transaction wasn't an INSERT at all, the insertId-property of the resultSet contains this message instead of the ID of the last inserted row.

http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#SQLResultSet

Answer (score 7):

I had this and it was driving me completely crazy.

What happens is that, if the operation is not an INSERT statement, the insertId is nullified, since no rows have been inserted, but instead of just showing 0 it gives a cryptic DOM error.

You simply have to ignore it and concentrate on the rows.

The big question is why the hell have it in the first place, why not just have a sqlInsertResultSet and a sqlRetrieveResultSet and stop messing with our minds :(

Answer (score 5):

On my side following gave the mentioned error:

```
results.rows[0].x
```

and this worked:

```
results.rows.item(0).x
```