# DOMException in WebSql Resultset

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite, web-sql, domexception

I've been querying a websql database table. Here, the insert and remove statement works fine.

But when I try to execute findAll query, essentially the **'select * from myTable'**, it returns a **SqlResultSet with DOMException**.

I only have two tables. One for product, another was created automatically, named **'sqlite_sequence'**

But the **rows** property of **Resultset Object** has correct **lenght**. Just one property shows

```
insertId: [Exception: DOMException]
```

Answer (score 1):

On my side following line gave mentioned error:

```
results.rows[0].x
```

while following worked:

```
results.rows.item(0).x
```

Answer (score 0):

Though it has been a few days since your question: 
A similar question was asked a few years ago. You can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586618/whats-the-meaning-of-this-error-message-insertid-error-invalid-access-err-d).
As long as your statement works fine, it shouldn't be a problem. But you probably should check your previous insert statements again.